# Unity - Printing all of the methods cast in a delegate event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, unity-game-engine

I'm casting methods into a delegate event.

```
TriggerPressed += new InteractionEventHandler(DetectManipulation);
```

When I try to remove some of the methods however, it seems like it doesn't always remove properly.

```
TriggerPressed -= DetectManipulation;
```

The event still gets triggered even with the method supposedly disassociated.

I'd like to be able to somehow print out the list of methods under a given delegate. Is there some way I can do this? Or am I not understanding something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are looking for [Delegate.GetInvocationList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist(v=vs.110).aspx) method